# Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS) best practice for clustering

Tags: active-directory, cluster, ad-lds

We decide to use Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS) for our application. But we cannot find the guide for clustering this service. Can anybody suggest or give a link to the best-practice for clustering Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS).

Comment: This is a duplicate question. http://serverfault.com/questions/281672/active-directory-ad-best-practice-for-clustering

Comment: No. AD LDS is not the same as AD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as with AD, you don't cluster AD LDS using MSCS. You configure it to have replication across LDS servers (just as AD, so you don't have shared storage like you need with clusters). There's (as near as I can tell) a feature called a Service Connection Point, which publishes the instance information into AD, so that clients can just bind to an instance, not one or more specific LDAP servers (LDS servers).

/edit - also, it appears that you can use NLB to front-end AD LDS. That will also handle the front-end connection in a HA manner.

Comment: Thanks. But what about logical "cluster" IP. Can I access service (built in such way) using  one IP for two physical instances of the LDS servers?

Comment: The MS docs that I skimmed through seem to indicate that defining a Service Connection Point is what does that. In normal AD, the dcpromo process adds every DC's IP to the A records for the domain. I imagine that publishing the SCP is a similar process. But really, at this point, you would do yourself the best favor by actually *reading the vendor documentation* and then coming back here with any further questions.